# Pandas: count the values for a range of 0.001, so count between 0 to 0.001 then count between 0.001 and 0.002 etc

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group my values (CPA%) by a specific range (0,1;0,2;etc).
For now my code looks like:

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_ob_indicators;")
row = cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(row,columns=['timestamp', 'topAsk', 'topBid', 'CPA', 'midprice', 'CPB', 'spread', 'CPA%', 'CPB%'])
pd.cut(df,0.001)
```

And my output like:

```
CPA%
0.005822
0.007129
0.008345
0.022531
0.016073
0.013433
0.013616
0.016571
```

How can I group by these values by a specific range and count them? I am rahter new to the library pandas and do not correctly understand how to use it...

Comment: Can you add the CPA column in a way that can be copied into a text editor?

Comment: Duplicate of your earlier [Pandas: need to count the number of values of a column between 0 and 0.001 then 0.001 and 0.002 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53962012/9209546). That question already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `cut` here, using `//` with `value_counts`

```
(df['CPA%']//0.001).value_counts()
Out[628]: 
13.0    2
16.0    2
22.0    1
8.0     1
7.0     1
5.0     1
Name: CPA%, dtype: int64
```

Let us try another option

```
import numpy as np 

np.floor(df['CPA%']*1000).value_counts()
Out[637]: 
13.0    2
16.0    2
22.0    1
8.0     1
7.0     1
5.0     1
Name: CPA%, dtype: int64
-
```

Comment: I have that "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'Decimal' and 'float'", does it come from the pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Viktor.w what is your pandas version ?

Comment: I have the following version: u'0.23.4'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers your question, but a quick solution will be to create a new column in pandas where you make the range groups. Something like:

```
df.loc[:,'range_group'] = np.where(df.CPA >0.75, 1, np.where(df.CPA > 0.5, 2, np.where(df.CPA> 0.25, 3, 4)))
```

Then you do a groupby, for example, counting rows on each range group:

```
df.groupby('range_group').CPA.count()
```

Just change, count() to whatever function you want.
Is this what you want?

Based on your comment below, it seems you need this:

```
steps = [0,0.001, 0.002, 0.003, ....,1]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.CPA, steps)).count()
```

Comment: Yes more or less, in fact I would like to count every values between 0 and 0.001 and then count every values between 0.001 and 0.002 etc...

Comment: Check my edits. I think the added script does what you want.